# Keystore and truststore issue with elasticsearch and searchguard ssl

Tags: java, ssl, elasticsearch, keystore, truststore

Let me give a little bit of background before I ask the question, so that we have clarity on the problem itself. We need to support one way SSL with Elasticsearch (v5.2.x), using searchguard ssl. We have a list of procedures for developers (not for production), which takes care of generating a self signed SSL cert. Here we've one root (locally created) and the actual cert. If we import the keystore (containing the private key and signed cert) and the truststore (containing the root cert) everything works fine.

But couple of days back, we got one request from a client. There, in production we need to support SSL. So, we followed the steps below:

1. with our script, we generated the private key, imported it into the keystore, and also generated the csr.
2. We gave the client the csr. He got it signed by a proper CA, and gave us back the cert.
3. Now the chain of trust is of length 3, for the cert given. So, there's a root CA, which signed the cert (issuer1), which signed the cert (issuer2), which in turn signed the actual csr.
4. For importing the actual cert to the keystore, we imported all the three parents, and then imported the actual cert.
5. Then we removed all the parent certs from keystore. So, now the keystore has only the private key and the actual cert.
6. We imported all the three parent certs into the truststore.

Now, if we start Elasticsearch, the following error is thrown: `[ERROR][c.f.s.s.t.SearchGuardSSLNettyTransport] [uyyIg3i] SSL Problem Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`

Funny thing is, the exact procedure works, if we have only the root ca, signing the actual csr. Any help is appreciated for figuring out the root cause of this issue, as I'm sort of out of ideas now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After couple of tiresome debugging sessions, we found out the CN-name and the actual host-name to be different. After making both of them same, we got it working.

Comment: Pls ask Search Guard questions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/search-guard